# Opel vectra 1997 temperature gauge not working

Tags: opel, thermostat, fuse-panel

I have 97 Opel vectra, temperature gauge stopped working all of a sudden, I first suspected that the thermostat failed so, I made sure I got 12V from the input wire then I just replaced the thermostat and still the same problem... is there a fuse or something from me to check before going to a mechanic?

Comment: Is the (electrical) temperature sensor located *on* the thermostat? Many cars have a mechanical thermostat, and an electrical temperature sensor which is *not* attached to the thermostat.

Comment: @Sam I have no idea, I thought it was the thermostat's job to send the temperature to the gauge, isn't it?

Comment: No, the thermostat is purely mechanical, and controls the flow of coolant.  There will be a coolant temperature sensor, an electrical component, somewhere else on the block.